# The text that I retrieved from my firebase database does not appear in my List View

Tags: android, listview, firebase-realtime-database

This is the screenshot of my database:

[image: db screenshot]

This is the activity:

```
private ListView dishList;
private Button bAddNewDish;
private DishListAdapter dishListAdapter;
private FirebaseDatabase mFireDb;
private DatabaseReference mDbReference;
private ChildEventListener mChildListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dishes);

    dishList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dishList);
    bAddNewDish = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAddNewDish);

    mFireDb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mDbReference = mFireDb.getReference().child("dishlist");
    ArrayList<DishElement> dishArray = new ArrayList<>();
    dishListAdapter = new DishListAdapter(this,R.layout.dish_item_element,dishArray);
    dishList.setAdapter(dishListAdapter);

    mChildListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            DishElement dishElement = dataSnapshot.getValue(DishElement.class);
            dishListAdapter.add(dishElement);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            DishElement dishElement = dataSnapshot.getValue(DishElement.class);
            dishListAdapter.add(dishElement);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            DishElement dishElement = dataSnapshot.getValue(DishElement.class);
            dishListAdapter.add(dishElement);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    mDbReference.addChildEventListener(mChildListener);

    bAddNewDish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(),AddDish.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

}

This is the adapter:

```
public class DishListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DishElement> {

public DishListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList<DishElement> dishElements) {
    super(context, resource, dishElements);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    DishElement dishElement = getItem(position);

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from((Activity) getContext()).inflate(R.layout.dish_item_element,parent,false);
    }

    TextView dishName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dishName);
    dishName.setText(dishElement.getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

}

I get null as value with `dishElement.getName()` method. The database connection seems to be working fine but I am not getting this string value whenever a child node is added in my database.

Comment: post your image within the question

Comment: @Benjamin Posting images requires a certain amount of reputation, which Mohammed doesn't yet have. The reason for that is that users new to Stack Overflow tend to post images of their code or other textual content. Such as the JSON here. Mohammed: please replace the link to the JSON screenshot with the actual JSON as text please. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problems in reading data because your fields are not named correctly. To solve this, please use a model class that looks like this:

```
public class DishElement {
    private String description, image, menuId, name;
    private double price;

    public DishElement() {}

    public DishElement(String description, String image, String menuId, String name, double price) {
        this.description = description;
        this.image = image;
        this.menuId = menuId;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getDescription() {return description;}

    public String getImage() {return image;}

    public String getMenuId() {return menuId;}

    public String getName() {return name;}

    public double getPrice() {return price;}
}
```

**To actually read the data correctly, remove the old data from your database and add fresh one.**

To read data, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference dishListRef = rootRef.child("dishlist");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            DishElement dishElement = ds.getValue(DishElement.class);
            dishListAdapter.add(dishElement);
            Log.d("TAG", dishElement.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
dishListRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

As you can see, I have added a log statement to print out the names using:

```
dishElement.getName()
```

In this case will work for sure. In your case didn't work because Firebase was looking for a field named `name` and not `Name` (capital N).

Comment: This fixed my problem. Really appreciate your help, Alex.